# Android MTP Device mode communciate with host?

Tags: java, android, mtp

I understand that MTPDevice is used when I want to talk to a downstream device, while the local Android system operates as a host.  But, I am trying to do the opposite.  Are there any facilities to allow devices running on an android device to communicate to a host over MTP?  I.e. with MTPEvents, etc.

Mostly, I am looking for a way to communicate data to a host PC (via libusb, etc.) while the Android device remains in MTP mode.  I am trying to avoid reliance on USB Accessory mode because it is not supported on all Android devices, while MTP support is virtually universal.

Comment: The service that acts as USB-MTP client is part of the Android system and to my knowledge there is no API to communicate with this service or change it's behavior. Therefore on an unrooted device I don't think this is possible, unless you create temporary files or something else the MTP client recognizes.